# How is composer including a dependent module?

Tags: composer

I have a composer managed Drupal project based on [drupal/recommended-project](https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project/blob/9.1.x/composer.json).

I'm installing a contrib module, [domain_group](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_group), and I'm seeing that composer is auto-including a required dependency, even though it's not listed in the module's composer.json. (I'm checking some other contrib modules and it seems that this is not specific to this module, but a consistent pattern across many modules.)

I run:

```
composer require drupal/domain_group
```

and it installs domain_group and domain_site_settings.

Then when I run:

```
composer why drupal/domain_site_settings
```

and it tells me that drupal/domain_group requires it.

While the dependency is not listed in domain_group/composer.json, I do see that it is listed in domain_group.info.yml.

Is composer somehow looking to the .info.yml to check for dependencies? Is this some kind of Drupal magic? What causes this? How does it work?

**Update:**

It seems that it's not checking the .info.yml, at least not locally. From @Clive, in the comments:

> [`composer why` still lists the dependency] even when [the reference to domain_site_settings] is not in domain_group's local composer.json, composer.lock is deleted, the require line in domain_group.info.yml is commented out and composer cache is cleared (just checked). Where is it getting the reference?

I'm now wondering if `composer why` checks the remote repositories, e.g. https://packages.drupal.org/8, and if there's something special about the d.o repository that compiles extra package dependencies from .info.yml files.

**domain_group/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "drupal/domain_group",
    "type": "drupal-module",
    "description": "This module provides integration between Domain and Group modules",
    "homepage": "http://drupal.org/project/domain_group",
    "authors": [], // etc... 
    "support": {}, // etc...
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "drupal/core": "^8.8 || ^9",
        "drupal/group": "~1.0",
        "drupal/domain": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

**domain_group/domain_group.info.yml**

```
name: 'Domain Group'
type: module
description: 'This module provides integration between Domain and Group modules.'
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
package: 'Domain'
dependencies:
  - group:group
  - domain:domain
  - domain_site_settings:domain_site_settings # Is composer somehow respecting this?
```

Comment: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/domain_group/-/blob/2.x/composer.json#L28 

Comment: That's interesting.. That's not what I see after installing the module OR when I download the 2.0.0 tar.gz from the project page. Though I do see it when I download 2.x-dev version from the project page. (I guess you can see that it was committed there after the release)

Comment: `Is composer somehow looking to the .info.yml to check for dependencies?` Yes, always. `Is this some kind of Drupal magic?` You betcha.

Comment: The Drupal packager does do some magic with .info.yml files, but that doesn't really explain why a local `composer why` finds that package, even when it's not in domain_group's local composer.json, composer.lock is deleted, the require line in domain_group.info.yml is commented out and composer cache is cleared (just checked). Where is it getting the reference?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, Clive. I added it to the question.

Comment: _I'm now wondering if composer why checks the remote repositories_ It doesn't, still works with network connection disabled...I'm sure there's a simple explanation for this but I can't see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is what's happening:

1. The Drupal packager gets dependencies from domain_group.info.yml, and adds them to the dependencies for the package record that composer will use.
2. When composer installs the package, it downloads the current version of the module code (which doesn't have the dependency in composer.json)
3. Composer doesn't use that composer.json for its record keeping - it stores the dependency from the packager in composer.lock, and also in vendor/composer/installed.json
4. `composer why` seems to use composer.lock first for its info, falling back to installed.json if unavailable.

So it doesn't really matter what's in the module's composer.json as far as Composer commands are concerned - it's looking at composer.lock or installed.json, which has domain_site_settings as a requirement from the original install.

Comment: Yeah, this matches what I see. The Drupal packager must be working some magic here to mark to list the initial dependency. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any documentation out there about the "Drupal packager"? Seems rather hard to find something about it.